# onCreate android os bundle is never used

Tags: java, android

I'm a noob in java android but I get this error when I hover onCreate `method onCreate(android.os.Bundle) is never used`. Should I worry about this error?

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Feed").setTabListener(this));
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Browse").setTabListener(this));
    actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Settings").setTabListener(this));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Add the entire code, is this the code of an activity or....?

Comment: Does the class this code is in `extends Activity`?

Comment: `extends FragmentActivity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I just changed `extends FragmentActivity` into `extends Activity` and imported `android.app.Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

thats not an error its a warning. the bundle is used for putting information in when the app changes state ie. orientation so you can continue where the user left off.

there is no harm in not using it however the activity will be shown just as it would if you were to launch it from the launcher.